# Property does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to render image while using React with typescript.

```
...
<img src="(ommitted for clarity)" width="400" heigth="400"/>
...
```

And getting such error:

```
Type '{ width: string; heigth: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>'.
Property 'heigth' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>'.ts(2322)
```

some of the packages included in webpack:

```
"@types/jest": "^24.0.11",
"@types/node": "^11.13.6",
"@types/react": "^16.8.15",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.8.4",
"@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.9",
```

Is there a way to circumvent this error? Maybe it is enough to make some type declaration? In react and typescript sandbox no such error is present.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTps6.png)

Answer (score 2):

Height is misspelled.

```
<img src="(ommitted for clarity)" width="400" height="400"/>
```

Comment: I am so dumb :(

Comment: This should be deleted, as it has no value for others, i am unable to delete it.

Comment: I think its because my answer is up-voted. If you up-voted it you might be able to undo it and then delete it? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222